# TYPO3 - Footer Incomplete - Missing part only on start page working

Tags: mysql, css, xhtml, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

TYPO3 6.2.9
Installation: http://www.youpromi.com

My working signature/footer area with TYPO3 works fine. I ran into a problem, related to the footer. It works fine, all elements where displayed correctly on the start page. All sub pages are missing one text box in the footer page.
I can't find any limitations or restrictions to display it only at the front page.

To give you an overview, here is the SQL content for that footer section:

```
REPLACE INTO `tt_content` (`uid`, `pid`, `t3ver_oid`, `t3ver_id`, `t3ver_wsid`, `t3ver_label`, `t3ver_state`, `t3ver_stage`, `t3ver_count`, `t3ver_tstamp`, `t3ver_move_id`, `t3_origuid`, `tstamp`, `crdate`, `cruser_id`, `hidden`, `sorting`, `CType`, `header`, `header_position`, `bodytext`, `image`, `imagewidth`, `imageorient`, `imagecaption`, `imagecols`, `imageborder`, `media`, `layout`, `deleted`, `cols`, `records`, `pages`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `colPos`, `subheader`, `spaceBefore`, `spaceAfter`, `fe_group`, `header_link`, `imagecaption_position`, `image_link`, `image_zoom`, `image_noRows`, `image_effects`, `image_compression`, `altText`, `titleText`, `longdescURL`, `header_layout`, `zzz_deleted_text_align`, `zzz_deleted_text_face`, `zzz_deleted_text_size`, `zzz_deleted_text_color`, `zzz_deleted_text_properties`, `menu_type`, `list_type`, `table_border`, `table_cellspacing`, `table_cellpadding`, `table_bgColor`, `select_key`, `sectionIndex`, `linkToTop`, `filelink_size`, `target`, `section_frame`, `date`, `zzz_deleted_splash_layout`, `multimedia`, `image_frames`, `recursive`, `imageheight`, `rte_enabled`, `sys_language_uid`, `tx_impexp_origuid`, `pi_flexform`, `accessibility_title`, `accessibility_bypass`, `accessibility_bypass_text`, `l18n_parent`, `l18n_diffsource`, `file_collections`, `filelink_sorting`, `selected_categories`, `category_field`, `icon`, `icon_position`, `icon_size`, `icon_type`, `icon_color`, `icon_background`, `tx_bootstrappackage_carousel_item`, `tx_bootstrappackage_accordion_item`, `categories`) VALUES (172, 1, 0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1439739838, 1439739074, 1, 0, 2304, 'html', '', '', '<h1>YouPromi</h1>\n<h3>1st Multinational Music</h3>\n<p>YouPromi.com constitutes your brand-new featured public music platform. It contains a wide range of audio-visual contributions: Artists from over 35 countries present trendy music videos and tracks – just click and enjoy this global music platform.<br />Are YouPromi?</p>', NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 2, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 10, '', 0, 0, '', '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, '0', NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '', 0, '', 0, 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, NULL, '', NULL, '', '', '', 0, 0, '#FFFFFF', '#333333', 0, 0, 0);
```

To get a complete view of my meanings, try to open http://youpromi.com to get an own view. Related are all sub pages you find through the navigation buttons on the site. Only the start / first page after opening YouPromi display the footer correctly.

Using the default bootstrap included in the demonstration package. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a good work around. Just removed the typoscript variable in the bootstrap package's link to show the footer. Simply replaced with the template I created for the footer area. Works perfectly and it's still editable to take changes centrally.